# Serialization error when sending email with .deliver_later

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sidekiq, rails-activejob

I have a signup controller action that sends an email confirming registration. It works if I use .deliver_now, but if I try to .deliver_later I get this:

> ActiveJob::SerializationError in Users::UsersController#process_signup
>
> Unsupported argument type: Time

My code:

```
Emails
  .with(template_data: processable_data.merge({:user => @u.safe_attributes }))
  .signup_inactive
  .deliver_later # not even passing a time to deliver the message at
```

The template_data is a hash with a bunch of user-specific attributes that may be used within the email template, I'm using Liquid for that as they're edited by users. It includes some DateTime values (created_at/updated_at) but ActiveJob is supposed to accept Date/Time/DateTime values afaik?

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: what is @u ? You might try using @u.as_json

Comment: @u is an user object, contains standard attributes such as first name, last name, email, created at. .safe attributes basically selects some of its attributes and returns a hash. Will try .to_json, didn’t know it can detect/decode json!